# Quanto mais melhor? Ou um meio para dizer "se vira"?

Tags: debate

Nesse pergunta: [**Como interceptar exceções quando se trabalha com o EntityFramework?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21278/6026), o usuário tinha dúvidas sobre as exceções lançadas pelo [Entity Framework](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/). Como eu percebi pelas tags que a versão do EF seria **6+**, ela precisava usar no `catch` o [DbUpdateException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbupdateexception%28v=vs.113%29.aspx). Bom a pergunta teve a resposta que o OP queria.

Pergunta-se: Porque logo abaixo eu senti uma resposta forçada, tendo em seu meio um texto assim: **E você poderia ter descoberto isto por conta própria**. Então existem perguntas que não podem ser respondidas, por acreditar que o usuário poderia por conta própria achar, visto que *Entity Framework 6* é recente e mudou bastante coisa, inclusive a resposta cita que: ***Não conheço o EF mas de acordo com a outra resposta***?

Só queria lembrar que são pontos que eu percebi na resposta do OP @Bigown, a resposta em seu contexto tava boa tendo uma explanação sobre `Exception`, mas, esses pontos eu queria que a *comunidade* dessa sua opinião !!!

**Reedição**

**Perguntas?**

- É legal dizer ao OP: **E você poderia ter descoberto isto por conta própria**, lembrando que EF 6+ é a nova versão e veio com melhorias (pouco material ainda)?
- Não conheço o assunto como relatado: **Não conheço o EF mas ...**, então é bom responder assuntos desconhecidos?

Comment: Acho que ele não quis dizer que era uma pergunta errada. Humildemente acho que perguntas muito mais "toscas" (não me veio outra palavra) são criadas a todo tempo. Eu entendi que ele quiz foi aproveitar a oportunidade para compartilhar um pouco mais de conhecimento sobre o assunto. Bom, foi o que eu entendi.

Comment: @TremDoido eu acredito que não se deva fazer restrições sobre o assunto, é uma forma no meu entender de desmotivar quem pergunta !!! Todos temos direito de perguntar, e talvez ser agraciado com resposta, não é pessoal e realidade

Comment: Acho que a explicação tá no fim do texto da reposta: "Tentei mostrar como achar a solução por seus próprios meios, assim você pode se virar em outras situações"

Comment: @Bacco, eu vi tudo isso, mas, você não acha que isso vai limitar o que perguntar, e olhe, antes de responder eu procurei no site para ver se já tinha resposta do mesmo, como é uma versão nova, não tinha e foi respondido ... Ensinar a procurar não é o nosso lema aqui ou é, se estiver enganado eu não falo mais nada!

Comment: Bom, no começo já tinha explicação que não era substituta pra sua resposta, mas um complemento: "Vou te dar uma resposta que não responde diretamente o que você deseja mas que vai ajudar você e outras pessoas para **outros** problemas com exceções." (grifo meu). Quanto a ensinar procurar, não sei no caso desse assunto especificamente, mas eu acho que o maior problema do SOpt hoje é o pessoal perguntar sem pesquisar nada. Mas isso talvez não se aplique a esse caso, eu tb nao mexo com EF. Na verdade tou só compartilhando a opinião, como pedido, pois na realidade não consegui enxergar o problema.

Comment: Eu acho que você deu uma resposta que atende à pergunta, o @bigown fez um complemento mais geral, e as duas coisas devem ter sido boas pro OP e pra todas as pessoas que visitarem a pergunta no futuro. Mas vou acompanhar o andamento da comunidade aqui, pode ser que eu nao tenha compreendido direito o que você disse, e ao desenrolar o assunto e ver mais opiniões, vou me inteirando do assunto.

Comment: @Bacco é para compartilhar sim e eu agradeço a sua contribuição, mas, você mesmo falou eu não sei EF, e eu Bacco mexo desde versão 1.0 imagine o conhecimento que eu tenho e as exceções são de grande utilidade, usadas corretamente é claro. Obrigado muito mesmo

Comment: Você ofereceu um peixe, o @bigown ensinou a pescar. Acho que as duas coisas são boas.

Comment: Mas essa filosofia tá embutida no [se]! Tem gente que precisa de solução rápida *(toma um peixe)*, tem gente que quer aprender mais *(é assim que se pesca)*.

Comment: Realmente, o @Harry me deu a resposta e resolveu meu problema. Obrigado pelo peixe! (rs) O que o bigown trouxe na sequência foi algo complementar e acredito ser de grande importância.

Comment: Não me pareceu o @BigOwn fez alguma ofensa, ou tenha restringido o escopo de perguntas do SOPT ou mesmo tenha tentado rebaixar a outra resposta. Aliás, já levei muita "paulada" por não ter respondido da melhor forma, muitas pessoas já complementaram respostas minhas e outras vezes apresentaram outra abordagem. Só pude [aprender com essas experiências](http://luizricardo.org/2014/02/resultados-de-um-experimento-social/). :)

Comment: A opinião de alguém que já deu quase 14 mil respostas (!): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258562/1287812

Comment: @brasofilo você também não entendeu, o link reflete muito o que eu penso e faço ... olhas as minhas respostas! não é isso que eu to afirmando...

Comment: @utluiz, você não entendeu e muito gente porque até no chat estavam falando sobre o assunto ... ta dificil mesmo entender!

Comment: Será que o problema é nosso entendimento ou sua explicação?

Comment: O entendimento que vocês não querem enxergar @brasofilo ... e a minha chateação não é sobre a minha resposta, sobre o voto, mas, a conduta de não saber o assunto e mesmo relatar sobre o tal e ainda falar para o op que ele poderia encontrar, inclusive já existe uma resposta com essa explicação de exception no site poderia até ser levado como duplicata!

Comment: Harry, meu bom... o TremDoido, o Bacco, eu, e o utluiz, cada um tá entendendo uma coisa e você diz que não é coisa nenhuma. Por favor, **edite** a pergunta para esclarecer: 1) por que você acha que foi dito "se vira"? 2) O que há de "forçado" na resposta do bigown? 3) Quais são exatamente os pontos que você quer discutir?

Comment: @utluiz wow! Muito legal esse seu post no seu blog, não tinha lido ele ainda. Sabe quando você lê algo e se enxerga naquela situação? Senti exatamente isso, rsrs.. Principalmente sobre a estagnação e `talento e esforço não são sinônimos de reconhecimento e crescimento profissional` :/ Já to fazendo pós e tenho minha conta no SOPT, agora só falta um blog :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Com base na [resposta do Hans Passant no Meta SO.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258562/1964435) linkada pelo comentário do @brasofilo.

Existem pelo menos dois tipos de pessoas interessadas nas respostas:

1. Pessoas que querem aprender mais sobre o determinado assunto
2. Pessoas que querem terminar logo o serviço e estão agarradas naquele problema em específico.

Basicamente, para o primeiro caso "quanto mais melhor", para o segundo caso "quanto menos melhor" :)

Eu não cheguei a ler a pergunta nem as respostas do link que o Harry Potter postou, mas pelo que eu entendi o Harry tentou resolver o problema pontualmente, enquanto o bigown tentou mostrar a causa do problema junto com a solução.

Em resumo, não há nada de errado com nenhuma das duas respostas. Entretanto, o que eu costumo ver é que respostas que tentam explicar a raiz do problema e como ensinar as pessoas a evitar situações similares costumam receber mais votos, e muitas vezes se tornam canônicas, enquanto problemas resolvidos pontualmente muitas vezes acabam sendo de maior interesse apenas para o OP, consequentemente não recebe muita atenção e poucos votos.

Apenas para completar, você pode fazer as duas coisas em um só resposta, resolva o problema do OP logo nas primeiras linhas, em seguida você dá uma explicação da real causa do problema. Cada público vai dar mais atenção para aquilo que mais lhe interessa.

Comment: o tempo dirá...

Comment: @HarryPotter, em vez do tempo, acho que seria melhor *você dizer*, através de uma resposta completa, qual sua proposta para resolver os problemas que você percebeu ;)

Answer (score 8):

> É legal dizer ao OP: **E você poderia ter descoberto isto por conta própria**

Sim, especialmente se você ensina como "descobrir por conta própria".

> Não conheço o assunto como relatado: **Não conheço o EF mas ...**, então é bom responder assuntos desconhecidos?

Sim, especialmente se você tem gabarito suficiente para escrever sobre algo que desconhece baseado naquilo que conhece. Num caso desse, as pessoas que conhecem o assunto vão avaliar votando positiva ou negativamente a resposta.

Vale dizer que, estando dentro do tópico perguntado pelo OP, qualquer resposta é válida, sendo que a comunidade e os profissionais da área vão avaliar se a resposta é boa ou não usando as ferramentas que o site oferece: Comentários e Votos.

Comment: Discordo de vc, mas respeito sua opinião. Obrigado

Answer (score 6):

> É legal dizer ao OP: E você poderia ter descoberto isto por conta própria, lembrando que EF 6+ é a nova versão e veio com melhorias (pouco material ainda)?

Antes de mais nada, o próprio OP comentou defendendo o @bigown, então ele não se sentiu ofendido.

E respondendo exatamente à pergunta, é apropriado dizer isso. Ficou claro que a intenção do @bigown não foi dizer que o OP não deveria ter feito a pergunta e resolvido sozinho, mas que ele iria explicar o que estava acontecendo de modo que no futuro ele poderá resolver esse tipo de problema sozinho.

Em resumo, o que você viu como uma ofensa ou um puxão de orelha, na verdade é apenas um conselho.

Imagine um diálogo entre duas pessoas:

> João: Ana, você poderia me ajudar com esse erro?
>
> Ana: Claro, João! Mas você pode resolver isso sozinho se quiser. Deixa eu explicar só algumas coisas...
>
> (5 minutos depois)
>
> João: Ah! Agora compreendo onde foi que errei. Agora que entendi o problema não preciso mais de sua ajuda toda hora.

---

> Não conheço o assunto como relatado: Não conheço o EF mas ..., então é bom responder assuntos desconhecidos?

Você está equivocado. Embora a exceção seja do EF, o assunto é sobre tratamento de exceções.

É muito comum novas exceções serem acrescentadas em *releases* de frameworks. O que eu faço? Tiro uma nova certificação para aprender profundamente sobre todas as mudanças? Claro que não! Basta dar uma rápida olhada no nome da exceção, acrescentar um `catch` no lugar mais adequado e pronto.

Eu mesmo respondo perguntas aqui todos os dias sobre tecnologias Java que não conheço, já que eu domino os fundamentos desta plataforma. Não preciso conhecer o framework X, Y ou Z para saber como capturar uma exceção declarada nos métodos que ele usa. Quinze minutos de pesquisa de alguém experiente pode resolver o problema que um desenvolvedor júnior simplesmente levaria dias.

A frase "não conheço bem X", neste caso, serve como um alerta de que talvez haja alguma forma melhor de fazer isso específica de X. Na verdade, algumas vezes a pessoa diz isso por pura humildade.

Enfim, não se apegue a um recurso de linguagem. O que está escrito ali é coerente? Ou você acha que está errado e quer refutar?

Comment: Desculpa não concordo com nada que você disse!

Comment: E outra não ensina o padre a rezar! eu sei bem o que é exception ... e como sei!

Comment: @HarryPotter E onde o utluiz disse (ou mesmo insinua) que você não saberia o que é exception? Você está enxergando coisa que não existe!

Comment: @HarryPotter Você está enxergando pelo em ovo. 
**Vou dar aqui minha opinião particular como pessoa (não como profissional e muito menos como moderador do SOPT).** Parece que você está lutando contra todos. Quer ter razão mesmo sem apresentar qualquer argumento sólido a seu favor e usa como desculpa que ninguém lhe entende. 
Está ficando claro que você está levando os comentários e respostas para o lado pessoal e fica muito facilmente ofendido por coisas que possa vir a sugerir algo relacionado a você.
Talvez pense que estamos concorrendo com você de alguma forma. Saiba que não é o caso!

Comment: @HarryPotter Além disso, ninguém aqui está sugerindo que você não tem uma boa experiência e um ótimo *background* técnico, 
mas certamente lhe falta um certo tato com as pessoas, pelo menos neste ambiente virtual.
Há problemas claros com compreensão sobre o que vários usuários escrevem aqui no SO, como pode ser visto em seu comentário logo acima. 
O que está causando essa distorção não sei, mas procure se esforçar um pouco mais em sua leitura.

Comment: @HarryPotter Enfim, meu conselho pessoal é: pare de lutar por algo que não existe. 
Se você está vendo coisas que ninguém vê, talvez seja melhor esfriar a cabeça, repensar alguns conceitos e amadurecer algumas ideias.
Pense nos usuários aqui como em sua equipe. Você trabalha **com** eles, não **contra** eles. ;)

Comment: A luta não existe, o problema sim, mas @utluiz o tempo é o melhor remédio para aqueles que fecham os olhos pra realidade e não é nada pessoal deixando bem claro