# Ensinar a pescar, ou dar o peixe?

Tags: debate, perguntas, qualidade

Que tipo de resposta tenho que dar para perguntas como **[Algoritmo para geração de nomes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32163/algoritmo-para-gera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-nomes#32180)** ?

E Também

**https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32400/atividade-simples-sobre-sess%C3%A3o**

A pessoa pergunta, *"como eu faço X?"*. Eu respondo "*faça assim*". O correto é:

> faça assim + código.

ou apenas

> faça assim?

Eu geralmente falo como fazer, não mostro código (a menos que o usuário tenha iniciado algo com código). Não acho correto fazer o trabalho de escola para os outros, e vocês?

Comment: Relacionada: [Esclarecer ou fazer o trabalho pelos outros?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1157/esclarecer-ou-fazer-o-trabalho-pelos-outros)

Comment: Pra mim depende do grau de interesse da pergunta. Se é um bom desafio e a pessoa quer resolver, beleza. Parece que os +1 lá pensam parecido.

Comment: Trazendo pra cá [meu comentário inicial](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32163/algoritmo-para-gera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-nomes#comment60894_32178) na sua resposta lá. Se você acha a pergunta ruim, não precisa responder e ainda tem a prerrogativa de votar negativo. Creio que também tem reputação pra votar pra fechar. Abrir uma pergunta no Meta pra atrair atenção é outra opção, que já fez. Então, é tipo isso...

Comment: Relacionado: [O que fazer com usuários que estão na zona de conforto?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1137/3117)

Comment: Relacionado: [O que fazer com perguntas no estilo "Como fazer X?"](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105/o-que-fazer-com-perguntas-no-estilo-como-fazer-x)

Comment: Desanimei de participar aqui porque prefiro apenas indicar um caminho para que o autor da pergunta faça o trabalho dele. Acho que não sou obrigado a fazer o serviço de terceiros. Mas o problema mais chato é que vinha recebendo negativos por não postar uma resposta GIGANTE incluindo o trabalho PRONTO. Essa é a parte chata do SO. É você ser julgado não pela comunidade, mas por 2 ou 3, ou as vezes apenas 1 que tem maior privilégio que outros.

Comment: Sei como é @Daniel Omine

Comment: Meu comportamento depende bastante de como o cara se expressa ao perguntar. Se não quero responder bem completinho, com código exemplo e referências, só deixo um comentário na pergunta com links sobre o assunto e vou responder outra coisa.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Depende.**

## Ensinar

Pelo que vi nos comentários, você é professor, não é?

Ao lecionar programação, por exemplo, você não pode chegar para os alunos mostrando apenas a "ideia geral" de um algoritmo de ordenação e já mandá-los implementar tudo aquilo.

Não, você explica em detalhes, passo-a-passo, exemplificando e só depois pede para eles implementarem aquilo. Muitas vezes é necessário explicar mais de uma vez até todos entenderem.

Isso é dar o peixe? De forma alguma.

A "cobrança" de conhecer algo será numa prova ou posteriormente na vida real. Pode ser quando o recém-formado tentar um emprego e tiver que fazer um algoritmo na entrevista. Ou quando o programador tiver que trabalhar até mais tarde para resolver um problema mais complicado sobre algo que ele não aprendeu direito antes.

## É mesmo errado colocar um pseudo-código ou mesmo um código pronto?

Qualquer desenvolvedor sabe que reusar código aumenta a produtividade e muitas vezes é essencial.

Por exemplo, porque eu deveria aprender a calcular potências de números de ponto flutuante para fazer cálculo de juros compostos? Se o meu problema do dia-a-dia limita-se a calcular a taxa de juros correta para o cliente, não é de interesse meu ou do cliente gastar tempo em algoritmos matemáticos.

E mais, a não ser que esteja fazendo um doutorado, a melhor prática para resolver um problema é conhecer as soluções existentes (em forma de algoritmo) e reusá-las ou implementá-las na sua linguagem.

Temos de tomar cuidado ao assumir que programadores **deveriam** saber resolver certas questões, só porque nós já temos experiência e achamos aquilos simples. A realidade é que quase sempre que as pessoas reinventam a roda elas caem nos mesmos erros. Em geral, é melhor aprender com quem já trilhou o caminho das pedras.

Enfim, o que é melhor: que o aluno reinvente uma solução "porca" ou que aprenda uma forma já reconhecida de resolver um determinado problema? Creio que uma coisa não exclui a outra, mas na prática o segundo caso é mais produtivo.

## Sobre as respostas

As duas respostas existentes basicamente possuem o mesmo algoritmo básico. A diferença é que a sua resposta é extremamente simplista, não dá exemplos e não avalia o problema.

Não estou dizendo que é necessariamente ruim, mas respostas "curtas e secas" **geralmente** não são bem vistas pelos usuários, já que a maioria dos que votam está interessada em ver aprender algo novo.

Sua resposta exibe apenas uma solução *adhoc* extremamente simplista. Ela não avalia, por exemplo, a possibilidade de se gerar dois números aleatórios iguais e repetir uma sílaba, algo que alguém um inicialmente iria facilmente fazer sem perceber.

Outra coisa interessante na outra resposta é os exemplos de combinação de consoantes e vogais. Não sei de onde o usuário obteve aquelas letras, mas suponho que isso seja de grande valia para programadores que não entendem nada de fonética.

## Concluindo

Há vários pontos subjetivos na questão de uma questão ser uma "lição de casa" ou ter "falta de pesquisa". Muitas questões seriam resolvidas se o OP simplesmente lesse a documentação oficial da ferramenta ou tecnologia.

Porém, nos cabe apontar o caminho da solução (vara), assim como não deixar a pessoa sair com fome (peixei) até que ela aprenda a pescar por si só.

Comment: Eu entendi o ponto, só acredito que primeiro você fala o COMO FAZER, caso o cara realmente não consiga, você mostra o caminho e em último caso, você faz. mas eu entendi o ponto e o porque das criticas. tentarei explicar melhor nas próximas respostas.

Comment: @PauloHDSousa Concordo. É que no caso de um sistema de perguntas e respostas, dar a solução em código faz parte e é até bem vista. A analogia de sala de aula não funciona 100% aqui.

Comment: +1 pela resposta com uma explicação clara e +1 pelo comentário do @PauloHDSousa.

Answer (score 15):

## Dar a metáfora ou ajudar a escrever?

Essa alegoria do "ensinar a pescar ao invés de dar o peixe" vem sendo utilizada diversas vezes ao longo da história do SOpt mas algo nela nunca me agradou, mesmo que eu não conseguisse apontar *o quê* exatamente. Até que dessa vez atingi a iluminação, além de ter lido muitos outros bons argumentos nessa pergunta.

> Não escrevo isso em relação ao autor dessa pergunta. Os "você" aqui empregados são **genéricos**

### O problema é de quem?

Meu desgosto pela frase, no final das contas, vem do fato de que ele pega um sentimento perfeitamente mundano, e algumas vezes beneficial ao site, e tenta mascará-lo como algo nobre, honrado. O problema não é que você teve uma má impressao da pergunta (porque ela tem cara de dever de casa), o problema não é que a pergunta é *ampla demais* (bem comum nas perguntas de dever de casa, por exemplo), o problema não é que você passou dificuldades pra aprender e agora guarda rancor de alguém que quer aprender "na moleza".

Não. O problema é que você é nobre demais para apenas "dar o peixe". Você quer ver a pessoa aprender. Olhe só, que iluminado. Que paladino. **Que balela**. Qual foi a última vez que você procurou a solução de algo na internet e ficou satisfeita em encontrar uma solução incompleta, que apenas te desse "o apanhado geral". Quando você tem um problema, quer encontrar uma resposta.

### Perguntas e Respostas

O @utluiz [disse muito bem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1968/ensinar-a-pescar-ou-dar-o-peixe/1971#comment6068_1971):

> (...) A analogia de sala de aula não funciona 100% aqui.

Não funciona porque quem vem aqui tem, na maioria das vezes, um problema real a ser resolvido, seja para faculdade, trabalho, projeto pessoal, o que for. Problemas reais precisam de respostas. Só assim o site pode ser útil e é isso que todos nós queremos dele.

Se a resposta tem jeitão de "*vou fazer o trabalho de alguém*", é porque provavelmente há um problema com a pergunta. Fornecer uma resposta incompleta na mesma medida, sob a justificativa de estar **ensinando a pescar** é colaborar com algo que podia ser resolvido de outra maneira.

O @utluiz também tocou no ponto dos diferentes domínios de conhecimento, em que o que é "conhecimento básico" para você é apenas o bug das 3 da tarde para a programadora de Portugal que fez a pergunta. E, como [o @brasofilo disse](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1988/12), o pessoal que faz uma busca no Google, arruma uma resposta e depois some é a maior parte de quem visita o SO. E pra eles, uma resposta do tipo "peixe" é a salvação.

## Então melhor deixar com fome

Como eu disse, não gosto de mascarar um problema que provavelmente está na pergunta (ou na sua percepção da pergunta) debaixo de uma capa de nobreza. E você também não gostaria de receber uma resposta incompleta com um bilhetinho escrito "É para o seu bem! xoxo".

Se você acha que a pergunta é uma tarefa de casa, comente. Diga à autora que perguntas assim **tendem** a ser mal vistas e que talvez seja melhor reformular, de modo a deixar mais claro qual o problema. Ou, caso seja possível, até mesmo edite. Se não quiser fazer nenhum dos dois, vá para a próxima. Outra pessoa pode estar mais disposta a escrever um longo algorítimo da época da faculdade e não há nada de errado nisso.

A autora da pergunta sai feliz, o site é útil e ninguém vai morrer falida e morando na rua porque "uma vez um site me deu o peixe ao invés de me ensinar a pescar, e eu fiquei preguiçosa!".

Falhando isso, é provável que a pergunta que quer o peixe seja simplesmente **ampla demais**. Então o mesmo conselho vale... Comente. Tente entender qual o problema específico do autor. Ajude ele a compreender o próprio problema e depois decida se quer ou não dar uma resposta. Ou faça nada e siga pra próxima pergunta no site.

## Peixaria Stack Overflow

A verdade é que o site existe para dar deliciosos peixes de todos os tamanhos. Ninguém aqui tem a "obrigação" de saber nada, do mais novato em programação ao mais ancião dos nossos habitantes. Estamos todos coçando as costas uns dos outros.

Comment: Sintetiza perfeitamente o que penso.

Comment: Mas cuidado para não confundir "ensinar a pescar" com "resposta incompleta" e "apanhado geral". Não é isso. Isso seria uma resposta ruim.

Comment: Eu já tenho minha barraquinha, 'Peixaria do Seu Ono'.

Answer (score 11):

Não existe "o correto". Você decide se mostra **também** o código ou não. Eu considero que explicação é fundamental em 99,999% dos casos, mas o código de fato não é. Mesmo assim não é errado incluí-lo se você quiser e/ou achar importante.

> Não acho correto fazer o trabalho de escola p/ os outros, e vocês?

Eu também não acho, mas como já [disse o utluiz](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1158/74), definir o que seja trabalho de casa é um pouco subjetivo. Além do mais, é um problema da pergunta e não da resposta. Se o enunciado é colado de um livro, apostila, prova, etc., geralmente eu não gosto. Não demonstra muito esforço por parte de quem pergunta. Não parece ser o caso da pergunta citada, que tem cara de um problema que o Marcony Felipe encontrou e se esforçou para pelo menos explicar. Pode não ser a melhor pergunta do mundo, mas acho válida e interessante, com potencial para gerar bons conteúdos para o site.

---

> **Disclaimer:** quando vi a pergunta eu lembrei que um colega meu uma vez criou um código exatamente para aquilo. E tentando incentivá-lo a participar do site, mandei o link da pergunta pra ele. Ele respondeu, e parece que foi a resposta dele que gerou esta discussão aqui no meta. Antes de responder, ele próprio me questionou se isso não seria "dar o peixe". Eu disse que se a resposta fosse bem explicada, seria vantajoso para o site. Que fique claro meu envolvimento com a resposta então, julguem como quiserem.

Answer (score 9):

## *Dar o peixe*

A primeira avaliação tem que ser: **a pergunta tem qualidade?**

- Se não tem muita certeza, passe para outra pergunta.
- Se achar que não mostra esforço de pesquisa ou que não é clara ou não é útil, vote negativamente:

  <kbd>[image]</kbd>
- Se achar que é off-topic conforme a [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) ou a meta-discussão [*Quais vão ser os tópicos do nosso site?*](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1216/quais-v%c3%a3o-ser-os-t%c3%b3picos-do-nosso-site), vote ou sinalize para fechar.

Normalmente, [quando respondo esse tipo de perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32331/201) é porque achei "clara e útil". Entendo o problema, me interessa pesquisar.

## *Ensinar a pescar*

Um dos perfis de quem visita o site é quem pesquisa um problema (normalmente Google), vem parar no SOpt, encontra a solução e continua com sua vida. *Copy/paste* no melhor estilo.
O SOen é uma maravilha para esses pequenos bugs do dia a dia.

Tem um outro perfil, que é a pessoa quer saber o *porquê* do problema.
Nessa hora, [aquela resposta toda detalhada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3Aanswer%20score%3A30..) é uma mão na roda.

## *O Estilo WikiStack*

A intenção do site é ser uma wikiteca de Problemas & Soluções. Uma [resposta só com um link é uma porcaria](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1913/posso-mostrar-s%C3%B3-um-link-pro-meu-site-com-problemas/1914#1914) porque a gente tem que ir para outro site para saber o final do filme. E muitas vezes esse outro site fechou as portas.
Uma resposta só com código é OK. *Mas e aí? O que isso significa?*

Quando a gente deixa uma resposta em uma pergunta inédita, dentro do escopo `pt.stackoverflow`, a chance disso virar número um (#1) no Google é muito grande. Tudo bem, o autor original pode até ser um [Vampiro de Ajuda](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1160/o-problema-dos-vampiros-de-ajuda), mas é somente **uma** das 500, 1.000, 10.000, *ad infinitum*, visitas que uma página pode ter.

*Se você quer seu nome aparecendo nessa página, acho melhor que seja da maneira mais profissional possível.*

<sub>*[**Referência cruzada**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1534/201): uma resposta do Hans, citada por mim, e analisada pelo Math.*</sub>

Comment: Já que você não destacou, eu destaco: "Se você quer seu nome aparecendo nessa página, acho melhor que seja da maneira mais profissional possível." :)

Answer (score 2):

Eu vou até evitar responder esses trabalhos de escola, não faz sentido, você responde e o povo negativa :)

O cara pergunta, como se faz X:

Eu respondo, assim que se faz X.

ele negativa porque não fiz p/ ele.

Comment: Bom, você não sabe quem negativou (adianto que eu não fui). Mas sua resposta ficou tão breve que está mais para um comentário, pode ter sido por isso.

Comment: entendi, resposta foi breve, mas com certeza respondia o que ele queria. mas eu entendi o que você disse. pode ser por isso.

Comment: Eu fui um dos que negativou, porque acho que a resposta além de breve não é uma boa resposta para o problema em questão, pelo menos no meu entender.

Comment: Compreendo, nem todos tem o mesmo intelecto, vou tentar explicar de uma forma mais simples da próxima.

Comment: "nem todos tem o mesmo intelecto" é sacanagem, hein? ;)

Comment: Muito bom ahahah. Isso é como responder a um problema matemático só com o resultado final. É uma resposta? É, mas és capaz de ter 0 na avaliação ;)

Comment: Ah, quando vc publicou isto só havia 2 votos negativos. Um do Jorge ^^^^ e outro meu. As razões já expliquei. No momento tá +3/-3. Tá no lucro!