# Responder 'como resolver' ou responder o que a pessoa quer?

Tags: debate

Foi feito essa pergunta:

[Gráfico highchart que importe os valores de tabela do banco de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/236953/gr%c3%a1fico-highchart-que-importe-os-valores-de-tabela-do-banco-de-dados/237124#237124)

A menina que perguntou, ao meu ver, quer fazer uma coisa de forma totalmente 'sem sentido', pois pode ser feita de outras formas mais eficientes e muito mais simples,bom, ela não conseguiu entender a resposta.

Poderia ter feito funcionar do modo que ela queria, mas seria uma parada esdrúxula pra funcionar.

Sabendo que a resposta que eu vou dar, vai ser o código que faz o que foi perguntado, pois tem certas perguntas que da pra perceber que se você der a receita de bolo a pessoa vai assar um peixe (não é o caso dessa pergunta, mas é o de várias), o que é melhor:

> Responder o o código que ela faça o que ela quer e do modo que a pessoa quer  (mesmo que seja uma resposta tosca)?
>
> Ou responder o código do 'jeito certo' correndo o risco da pessoa não entender/não querer ?

Comment: Relacionada: [Ensinar a pescar, ou dar o peixe?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1968/91)

Comment: Não foi isso que eu quis dizer, vou arrumar a pergunta kk

Comment: @rray, é um array de relacionadas? rs Todas as perguntas tem Relacionada: X.

Comment: @Stormwind funciono igual as recomendações da amazon ou netflix ooops xD

Comment: Vou falar uma coisa, essa usuária é complicada, ela fica repetindo a pergunta de diferentes maneiras e não sabe usar o básico do mysqli.

Comment: Eu percebi que não ia ter como ajudar, tanto que desisti de responder.

Comment: Hoje eu tive o mesmo problema com um topico aqui que uma mulher havia feito uma pergunta e eu identifiquei na pergunta dela o erro de sintaxe e depois ela achou ruim que eu não expliquei para ela todo o código dela, ou seja, ela usou um código que nem ela sabe o que faz e a culpa é minha

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sendo o StackOverflow um site de perguntas e repostas para ajudar quaisquer usuários a superarem problemas, então deve ter as respostas do jeito certo, pois não só ajuda a pessoa que fez a pergunta como outras futuras pessoas que se deparem com o mesmo problema.

Não adianta muito estar a dar uma solução errada que funciona para o problema que a pessoa tem, se ela mais à frente irá ter outros problemas.

E mesmo que não viesse a ter problemas, porquê ficar com uma solução mediocre se pode ter uma solução boa ?

Eu considero que deve até ser mais explicito e indicar porque não resolve da forma que a pessoa sugeriu, e quais os problemas ela que pode vir a encontrar se seguir esse caminho.

Eu vejo isso até como o classico [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%C3%A9-o-problema-xy)

Comment: Isso que você me perguntou me lembrou dessa pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/237151/64969. Nela, é deixado bem claro que AP já conhece X e já resolveu X, mas está tendo problemas em Y. Tentei ajudar (mas a ajuda não era válida no contexto da AP, contexto esse que eu não tinha percebido antes de responder). Para esses tipos de pergunta, como devemos nos portar?

Comment: Eu fico na dúvida em questões também que claramente a pessoa que perguntou não vai entender a resposta 'correta', da pra ter uma noção de quanto a pessoa sabe sobre aquilo com o enunciado da pergunta, essa é outra situação que complica em dar uma resposta boa.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Eu pessoalmente acho que a sua resposta nessa pergunta foi boa. Explica o motivo de não ter funcionado, e a solução que o autor estava a tentar não é claramente uma boa solução ao problema, mas pareceu me mais exercício academico que outra coisa.

Comment: @AnthraxisBR Sim, pode complicar se a resposta correta for um pouco mais elaborada que o conhecimento que a pessoa tem, e por isso eu acho que devemos tentar enquadrar a resposta até certo ponto e detalhar o máximo possível.

Answer (score 9):

### TL;DR

Os dois, com equilíbrio.

### Explico...

Para complementar as outras respostas e comentários, acredito que a dúvida advém de dois objetivos conflitantes:

1. Ajudar uma pessoa em particular a resolver um problema em particular
2. Ajudar o público em geral a resolver um problema comum

Idealmente, quando a pergunta e respostas são boas, os dois objetos podem ser alcançados.

Em outro casos, porém, pode ocorrer de uma situação particular não se encaixar bem no que geralmente aconselhamos para um público maior.

Sinceramente, no dia-a-dia, todo desenvolvedor faz concessões nas suas milhares de pequenas tarefas devido à restrições de recursos como tempo e dinheiro, mas claro que não fazemos disso um modelo para o mundo.

Por esta razão eu creio que não devemos condenar rapidamente os que querem tomar um atalho para determinada situação (não estou afirmando que é este o caso de hoje, mas falo em termos gerais), afinal uma coisa é um sistema em produção e outra é aquele script tosco no seu diretório de usuário para automatizar uma tarefa chata que só você usa e fica limitado ao seu computador.

Enfim, cada caso é um caso. O que geralmente eu tento fazer, ***se possível***, é apontar uma solução para o caso em especial ***e*** uma solução geral de melhor qualidade. Por exemplo:

> Para fazer o que você está pedindo, a solução XYZ resolve, mas é inseguro/tem baixo desempenho/é de difícil manutenção portanto o melhor seria a solução 123.

Se não for possível, opte por uma das duas e deixe um aviso, ou de que a solução não é a ideal ou de que você está dando a solução que seria ideal.

Comment: Acredito que essa resposta é um grande "trunfo". Em geral, em todos os contextos, e situações (mundiais), o que falta no ser humano, *é saber o equilíbrio e fazer esse equilíbrio acontecer*. Aqui no [pt.so] também não deve ser diferente, e deveriamos sempre tentar *equilíbrar*, tanto para darmos uma resposta de qualidade, e que ao mesmo tempo atenda ao solicitado.